# Ionic 2 Native Social Share error

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2

Hi I am trying to set up native twitter share for my Ionic 2 app. I have installed the cordova plugins correctly , included them in my app module , and the page component I am working with, my email share function is working fine indicating cordova and the social share is set up correctly. However when I try to use social share twitter

```
 this.socialSharing.shareViaTwitter("this is the message", "assets/images/port.jpg","https://futuresync.co.uk").then(()=>{
      //Sharing twitter successful
      console.log("Twitter share success");
    }).catch((error)=>{
      //Sharing twitter unsuccessful
      console.log("Twitter sharing unsuccessful");
      console.log(error);
    });
```

I get [this](https://gyazo.com/ab9d52b556125fff6edf573063dbe305) error.

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): com.google.android.apps.maps,com.google.android.apps.messaging

Any help would be great :)

Comment: It will not work on browser. Test it on an actual android device and it should work fine (given everything else works).

Comment: check whether twitter app is installed on your device or not

Answer (score 0):

It will not work on browser. Test it on an actual android device after building an apk using `ionic build android` and it should work fine (given everything else works).

Also, check if the permissions and settings in AndroidManifest.xml and config.xml are given properly. Like AndroidManifest.xml-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Check these things [here](http://%3Cuses-permission%20android:name=%22android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE%22%20/%3E).